# Make one solid from mesh built out of multiple squares by snapping to grid

Tags: mesh, vertices

I made a mesh out of multiple squares and there are an abundance of vertices throughout the entire mash. I want to make it so there is only vertices on the corners.

Do you know any way I can make it a solid object with only vertices at each corner of the object instead of having vertices all throughout the entire match?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, try crtl E > Un-Subdivide, play with the Iterations value in the Operator box

Comment: This did not help so much.

Comment: Hi. https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/ should help with taking clearer screenshots. The current ones are quite hard to see. Thanks.

Comment: maybe share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Select and remove all the verts inside.

Answer (score 2):

Blender is not Minecraft. You don't add boxes.

The best way not deal with unnecessary geometry is not to create it in the first place.

It makes no sense to have a whole bunch of duplicated faces just to delete them later.

Start your project over, and this time create just the shapes you need, with no internal faces. It will take you less time than to fix the current model and set you on the correct path to learn modelling.

Comment: I agree, this workflow will eventually lead to more and more work down the line

Comment: It has been said many times on this site. Topology is the object, not something to think about later.

Comment: Okay, I eventually guessed this was the case. Thanks and sorry.